# BASH blank alias to 'cd'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I am a happy BASH user. I do not want to switch to another shell (in this case ZSH).

ZSH has this ability to change a directory without necessarily typing:

```
cd /to/a/directory
```

What would be the correct alias (or maybe BASH function) to change directories without having to type `cd`?

On my above example, moving to /to/a/directory would be done like this:

```
/to/a/directory
```

I have tried:

```
alias ''='cd '
alias ""='cd '
alias " "='cd '
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If an empty alias were allowed as in your first two attempts, and if it worked the way you intended, then ALL commands would turn into "cd" commands.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's an option added in [version 4.0 of Bash](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES). You can set it with:

```
$ shopt -s autocd
```

Put that in your `.bashrc` file to enable it always.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I will have to wait on this one:
bash: shopt: autocd: invalid shell option name

Comment: I added the version information to the question, and linked to the changelog (it's under section 3 "New Features in Bash", item d)

Comment: @alfredodeza Well, you could do `shopt -s autocd 2> /dev/null`.  Then you can have the satisfaction of having the command there without the annoyance of the error message. :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you'll be able to have a "blank" alias, it doesn't really make sense..

bash version 4.0 added the `autocd` option, which is set by running `shopt -s autocd` (as mipadi answered)

There is no such option in previous versions of bash, annoying.

Comment: autocd aside, might have been able to get this by using traps, which could get ugly, but i think it would work to some degree...